# Complex Decision Tree Generator

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, tree, generator

I'm trying to write a sort of binary tree, but it's pretty large and I don't want to hold each element in memory. I would prefer to use a generator function to construct each node when required.

The tree models decision making in a game. The game starts with a frame of *n* options. The player selects two options (which cannot be the same), and combines them using different operations. So, a frame has *(n * (n-1)) * t* possible steps to take, where *t* is the number of operations.

Once a decision is made, it results in a new frame of *n - 1* options, where the two options chosen last time have been removed, but the result of those options has been included. The number of possible different choices is now *((n - 1) * (n - 2)) * t*. This process continues until number of options in the current frame <= 1.

I want to walk all possible routes through the decision tree in a specific way - full traversal of each route all the way down to the final frame (where *n* = 1), before moving on to the next possible route, which starts at the largest frame (size = *n*) but takes the next series of choices in each frame. The results the decisions have, apart from what I have described here, don't matter for these purposes. All routes must go all the way to the final frame (where *n* = 1) - I don't need to include partially traversed routes.

I have the following code which I want to generate a map of the decisions to make. :

```
public class PathStep
{
    public int FrameSize;
    public int Index1;
    public int Index2;
    public int Operation;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("F:{0} I1:{1} I2:{2} O{3}", this.FrameSize, this.Index1, this.Index2, this.Operation);
    }
}

public class Frame
{
    public int Size { get; private set; }

    public Frame(int size)
    {
        this.Size = size;
    }

    public IEnumerable<PathStep> AllPossibleSteps()
    {
        return this.step_helper(this.Size, 0);
    }

    private IEnumerable<PathStep> step_helper(int frame_size, int depth)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); //TODO
    }


    private static IEnumerable<Frame> frames_in_game(int initial_frame_size)
    {
        for (var i = initial_frame_size; i > 0; i--)
            yield return new Frame(i);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PathStep> steps_in_frame(int frame_size)
    {
        int op_count = Operation.Operations().Count();

        for (var first = 0; first < frame_size; first++)
        {
            for (var second = 0; second < frame_size - 1; second++)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < op_count; i++)
                {
                    yield return new PathStep() { FrameSize = frame_size, Index1 = first, Index2 = second, Operation = i };
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

How would I fill in my `step_helper` method to map each possible variation of decisions in the tree, and yield them in the order of consecutive games? I need to cover all possible routes, and `yield return` each step taken in a given route sequentially, but the order in which I take full routes isn't relevant, so long as I cover them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rethought my question, and realised the following:

If *n * (n -1) * t = options_per_frame*

Then I could represent each path as a grid of options, which (if 1 indexed) starts at:

```
   let t = 4

   n |n-1|t | n = ?
   1 |1  |1 | 6
   1 |1  |1 | 5
   1 |1  |1 | 4
   1 |1  |1 | 3
   1 |1  |1 | 2
```

Followed by:

```
   n |n-1|t | n = ?
   1 |1  |1 | 6
   1 |1  |1 | 5
   1 |1  |1 | 4
   1 |1  |1 | 3
   1 |1  |2 | 2
```

And ends with

```
   n |n-1|t | n = ?
   6 |5  |4 | 6
   5 |4  |4 | 5
   4 |3  |4 | 4
   3 |2  |4 | 3
   2 |1  |4 | 2
```

Where each value in a cell indicates the index/id of the option chosen, and the headers specify the maximum value that can be put in the cell. So, you could think of it a little like a clock - where "gears" of different sizes are used to rotate each other, so that changes cascade down with decreasing magnitude. In time, 1000ms "rotates" a second, 60 seconds "rotates" an hour, 24 hours "rotates" a day etc. So I created a `PathGrid` class which returned the next iteration of the grid, which allowed me to follow each path all the way through, without having to model a tree or use recursion. I have uploaded my solution [here](https://github.com/Osipion/countdown_maths_solver).